# Heroku - Deploy in Dev or Production

Tags: javascript, express, heroku, package.json, environment

I have an express API which I am hosting on **Heroku**. I created two projects: one project points at my Master Branch (Prod) and the other at my Development branch (Dev).

I have two scripts in my package JSON:

```
  "scripts": {
    "devStart": "export NODE_ENV=development && nodemon server.js",
    "start": "export NODE_ENV=production && node server.js"
  }
```

How can I make it so, that the development branch runs "DevStart" and Master runs "start". Currently Prod is working fine as `node start` is the default script.

I understand I can put commands in my `procfile`, however since both Dev and Prod use the same codebase, I would need to change this with each commit. Is there a dynamic way to do this?

Comment: What is your end goal here? It doesn't make much sense to use `nodemon` on Heroku even for a development or staging server. `nodemon` is primarily useful for watching changes to your source files, rebuilding, and updating the running application. That workflow doesn't work very well on Heroku.

Comment: nodemon is only there for when I am developing locally. My API relies on webhooks so the API in development mode needs to deployed. So I want to be able to commit code to either my master branch (prod) or development branch (dev). I have .env files for prod and dev that I want to use respectfully. However, Heroku always deploys in production as it uses web node start. For my development branch I want to use web node devStart. I  also don't want to have to depict this each time I deploy as there is a human error element with that process.

Comment: This is confusing, no matter what I do in the procfile, it will not run. It always runs Npm run start. right now I have a "Procfile" in the root of the code base is it has one line 'web:npm run devStart'. It just won't run that. I tried turning of the dyno but then nothing works.

Comment: "so the API in development mode needs to deployed"—not necessarily. You could use ngrok or localtunnel or similar and still work locally. Heroku is not a very good place to do development work.

Comment: No, I can't have local endpoints. I have webhooks one other software packages that are our dev environments as well. They can't hit local, this is why dev needs to be deployed. This API is one small part in a large chain of tools used for product distribution.

Comment: Like I said, you could use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) or [localtunnel](https://localtunnel.github.io/www/) or similar. They are services for routing external traffic to your local development machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, This might not be the correct way but here is how I did it.

I seen you can set the NODE_ENV variable for the Heroku app using terminal:

`heroku config:set NODE_ENV=development --app {app-name}`

My package JSON though was overwriting this when the app deployed.

```
  "scripts": {
    "devStart": "export NODE_ENV=development && nodemon server.js",
    "start": "export NODE_ENV=production && node server.js"
  },
```

I changed it to:

```
  "scripts": {
    "localStart": "export NODE_ENV=development && nodemon server.js",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
```

This now resolves the problem. No need for the `Procfile` or to setup environment variables within Heroku.

On Heroku I have two apps, one for production which I don't change the NODE_ENV variable as it defaults to production, and another for Development, which I do change the NODE_ENV variable to 'Development'.

Each app is hooked up to a different branch within the same code base ( Development(Development) & Master(Production) ). Any deploys to either branch will cause a rebuild using the correct NODE_ENV variable for each respective branch.